# Bootstrap wysihtml5 show extra strings

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I'm using [bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5) editor. On my web its working good. But when I send data from it to php using jquery it send some extra data. For example:

When I send this:

```
product two
```

It send the followings:

```
product+two%3Cbr%3E
```

My Bootstrap wysihtml5 configuration is here:

```
$('#form').wysihtml5({
    image: false
});
```

And my jquery ajax code is here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        contentEdit: $('#form').serialize()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('something ...');
    }
});
```

What is the procedure to avoid that?

Comment: Hi, please I'm wondering for this.

Comment: Looks like it's just url-encoding the data. You might have to url-decode it on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the problem was that I have used multiple form in one page. Otherwise it works within a framework that means when we integrate the Bootstrap wysihtml5, it's embedded through an iframe. Ultimately I have solved the problem by using [ckeditor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/). It is more flexible and easy to use. To easily use it you can follow its API documentation. Thanks to all.